# DOMDocument in Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, xml, domdocument, data-conversion

just wondering if its possible to convert this php script into rails

```
$c = file_get_contents('http://www.bunnings.com.au/products_category_plumbing-supplies_1637.aspx'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($c);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="details"]');

echo '<table>';

foreach($div as $details)
{
    $name = $details->getElementsByTagName('h4')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $price = $details->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $itemNumber = $details->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->nodeValue;

    $html = '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($price) . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($itemNumber) . '</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

    echo $html;
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Why should it not be possible?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a like function in Rails

Comment: You're trying to extract a html document and put it on your page? Of course it is possible. There are gems for this.

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev yes I am looking at the httparty gem looks like it might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is a Ruby Framework for web applications. What you are asking for is a simple Ruby script (which you could integrate in a larger Rails app, of course).

You can use the nokogiri gem to parse the HTML. On your terminal:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Then create a new .rb file like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.bunnings.com.au/products_category_plumbing-supplies_1637.aspx'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

div = doc.xpath('//div[@class="details"]')

# Well, I guess you should continue now
```

See http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html for some Nokogiri examples.